# How to better use match function in R

Tags: r, match

I am using `match()` in a function of mine, and I incurred in a small problem, which I fixed in a quick and dirty way. Here is the case:

```
# input can have max 4 numbers, unique, range 0-3:
test_numeric_input<- c(0,1,2,3)
# I want to get rid of 0, if present: 
test_numeric_output<- test_numeric_input[-match(0, test_numeric_input)]
```

Now, the problem is, if 0 is not there, the output is `NA`; if I use the option `nomatch = 0`, the resulting vector is empty (length 0).
My fix:

```
test_numeric_output<- test_numeric_input[-match(0,
  test_numeric_input, nomatch=99)]
```

The input vector max length is 4, so I just get the entire vector in case 0 is not present. I could also solve with an "if else" statement, I guess, but I was wondering if there are better solutions. The talking stick is all yours :)

Comment: Good point! Funny thing is, I tried to use it before resorting to match(), and threw me an error. Must have had some typo... >:P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v = 0
i = c(0,1,3,0,4)
i[!i %in% v]
# 1 3 4
# works for vector
v = c(0,4)
i[!i %in% v]
# 1 3
```

As mentioned in comment above for single value you could use

```
i[i != v]
```